# set title bar name of a activity

Tags: android, android-titlebar, custom-titlebar

I'm trying to change my applications activity menu bar title. I managed to change font as follows. Anyone help me to change the name of the title. It may be just a one line, but I can't figure it out.

```
int actionBarTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    TextView actionBarTitleView = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(actionBarTitle);
    if(actionBarTitleView != null){
        actionBarTitleView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you can do it your way or not but you can use the bellow solution:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // actionBar
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    // titleTextView
    TextView titleTextView = new TextView(actionBar.getThemedContext());

    titleTextView.setText("Title");
    titleTextView.setTypeface( your_typeface);

    titleTextView.setOtherProperties();

    // Add titleTextView into ActionBar
    actionBar.setCustomView(titleTextView);

}
```

By doing this solution, you have FULL control of your textview title.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

`getActionBar().setTitle("Your title");`

or this if you use appcompat-v7

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the title in action-bar using AndroidManifest.xml. Just add label to the activity. Like

```
<activity
       android:name=".DownloadActivity"
       android:label="Your Title"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer sets the default value without a boilerplate code. It's good to have it set instead of just setting it [with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29630920/5994041) otherwise the text change will be visible in UI on slower devices or emulators. For example switch from "com.some.package" to "MyApp".

Answer (score 2):

For the activity you want to change the title bar or action bar name, go to it's java file

for example if you want to change the name of `MainActivity` then go to `MainActivity.java` and add the following code

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("name of the action bar");`

below this code (it will be there by default)

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

in the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

It worked for me. I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `actionbar.setTitle` method.

```
getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

OR this if you are using appcompat

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

There is `setTitle` method in activity class as well.